# How to pass command line argument in .net windows application

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

i want to pass a argument in c#.net to a console application  i tried ProcessStartInfo
but that can be used for immediate run of an application ... but i want to set the arguments for the application which will run at scheduled time

Comment: Are you asking how to schedule a task to run in the future?

Comment: How are you scheduling the application? If you are using Windows Task Scheduler, then you can provide arguments while creating the task.

Comment: @JayantaDey yes i am using windows scheduler but i have created the scheduler in my application and scheduling task using the same...

Comment: Yes everybody i have solved the issue by creating a bat file in which i am writing the exe path along with the argument so when the scheduler runs the task at the specified time it will run the bat file which as written will run the exe and hence the argument will get passed.

Though i have achieved my objective by this i will appreciate a good answer i.e. without having any need to create a bat file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the arguments propery to pass command line arguments

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx

Example:

```
  var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
  info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
  info.Arguments = "/C";
  info.UseShellExecute = true;
  var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  process.StartInfo = info;

  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: this is working but only if i want to run the task straightaway but what if i want to schedule the task to run at specified time..then it doesn't work....